# React component self close on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which I want to self close when I click a button that's on the component itself.

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MyReactComponent = (props) => <div>

    <h1>TEST</h1>

    <button onClick={self close here?}>Self Close</button>

</div>

export default MyReactComponent
```

How can I get the button click to close the component when I click it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not how React works. :-) Instead, the parent of the component should pass it a property that it uses as the `onClick`. In response to the click, the parent component changes its state so that the child is no longer rendered:

```js
const MyReactComponent = (props) => <div>

    <h1>TEST</h1>

    <button onClick={props.onClose}>Self Close</button>

</div>;

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  // Note: This uses the class fields proposal, currently at Stage 3 and
  // commonly transpiled in React projects
  closeChild = () => {
    this.setState({
      showChild: false
    });
  };
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      showChild: true
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showChild && <MyReactComponent onClose={this.closeChild} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

More in the ["Lifting State Up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) part of the documentation.